# Ultimento Abandoned

Tags: theme, error

Commative Ultimento has closed their doors, leaving their users with 2 problems.

1. Annoying warning every time a page is opened in Magento Admin.

The fix: 
GO TO THIS FILE:

```
/app/code/local/Ultimento/Theme/Helper/Utils.php
```

COMMENT OUT THIS LINE AS FOLLOWS:

```
/*Ultimento_Theme_Helper_Utils::ultWarningDisplay($msg); */
```

1. 404 Error Message when Ultimento tries to validate your license.

GO TO THIS FILE:

```
/app/code/local/Ultimento/Theme/etc/config.xml
```

COMMENT OUT THESE LINES AS FOLLOWS:

```
<!--
      <adminhtml_block_html_before>
        <observers>
          <ultimento_log_in>
            <type>model</type>
            <class>Ultimento_Theme_Helper_Utils</class>
            <method>ultWarning</method>
          </ultimento_log_in>
        </observers>
      </adminhtml_block_html_before>
      <admin_session_user_login_success>
        <observers>
          <ultimento_log_in>
            <type>model</type>
            <class>Ultimento_Theme_Helper_Utils</class>
            <method>ultEvent</method>
          </ultimento_log_in>
        </observers>
      </admin_session_user_login_success>
-->
```

PROBLEMS SOLVED!!!

Answer (score 2):

I got an email on 28th April this year as I bought 2 copies of this theme for clients which said the following. If the community thinks it ok I can put the files needed online somewhere so the theme can be accessed by all?

> The Commative Team is sad to say that after a fantastic run, we must
>   now close our doors. Unforeseen personal circumstances have forced us
>   to move on from this great venture and we now look forward to the next
>   chapter in our lives. In honor of our great customers and the promise
>   of an open Internet, we leave Ultimento free and accessible to all who
>   have worked with us.
>
> There are three files that enable the validation functionality on
>   Ultimento. By substituting those three files on your server with the
>   ones provided below, you can bypass any checks against validation and
>   use Ultimento on as many sites as you like.
>
> ```
> /app/code/local/Ultimento/Theme/Helper/Utils.php
> /app/code/local/Ultimento/Theme/etc/system.xml
> /app/code/local/Ultimento/Theme/etc/config.xml
> ```
>
> Thank you for all your support and best of luck with your own Magento
>   enterprises.
>
> Sincerely,
>
> The Commative Team

Comment: Ok @benmarks said to add the open files I got from Commative before they shut down so please find the zip that I have placed on my own server here: http://thebloghouse.com/open.zip